# change slider value with interval

Tags: python, tkinter

I was working on python GUI and I am trying to link a variable and slider value, where it read the slider value in every 5 ms assign this value to the variable, I use root.after function but it shows not responding if the time interval is less than 200 ms. Is there any other way to do this??

```
    from tkinter import *
varible=0
varible2=0
def change() :
    variable=slider.get()
    Label(text="sampling : " + str(slider.get())).grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.after(5, change)

def change2() :
    variable=slider2.get()
    Label(text="sampling2 : " + str(slider2.get())).grid(row=1, column=2)
    root.after(5, change2)

root=Tk()
root.title("sampling")
root.geometry("300x200")
slidervar=DoubleVar()
slider=Scale(root,variable=slidervar,from_=0,to=10,label="sampling")
slider.grid(row=0,column=2)

slidervar2=DoubleVar()
slider2=Scale(root,variable=slidervar2,from_=0,to=20,label="sampling2")
slider2.grid(row=0,column=3)

Label(text="sampling : "+ str(slider.get()) ).grid(row=1,column=1)
Label(text="sampling2 : "+ str(slider2.get()) ).grid(row=1,column=2)
root.after(5,change)
root.after(10,change2)

mainloop()
```

when I check the time difference between consecutive change function using this code :

```
`from tkinter import *
from time import perf_counter_ns
global t1,t2,t3,t4
varible=0
varible2=0
root=Tk()
root.title("sampling")
root.geometry("300x200")
slidervar=DoubleVar()
slider=Scale(root,variable=slidervar,from_=0,to=10,label="sampling")
slider.grid(row=0,column=2)

slidervar2=DoubleVar()
slider2=Scale(root,variable=slidervar2,from_=0,to=20,label="sampling2")
slider2.grid(row=0,column=3)

Label(text="sampling : "+ str(slider.get()) ).grid(row=1,column=1)
Label(text="sampling2 : "+ str(slider2.get()) ).grid(row=1,column=2)
t1=perf_counter_ns()
def change() :
    global  t1,t2
    t2=perf_counter_ns()
    print(t2-t1)
    t1=t2
    variable=slider.get()
#    Label(text="sampling : " + str(slider.get())).grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.after(5, change)

def change2() :
    variable=slider2.get()
#    Label(text="sampling2 : " + str(slider2.get())).grid(row=1, column=2)
    root.after(10, change2)

root.after(5,change)
root.after(10,change2)
mainloop()
```

`
then the difference is more than expected

Comment: Please share your code, what you had tried. Please provide [mre]!

Comment: The question of timing accuracy is beyond the scope of your question. Your original question has been answered, your code is working. You should submit another question of tkinter timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modification to @Pooja Choudhary's code

It works... very fast!

I've made some changes to measure delay accuracy.

Run the code for a few seconds then press Escape key to quit and display Time analyzer results.

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randrange as rnd
from time import perf_counter_ns

# testing delay accuracy
delay = list()
result = list()

def change():

    delay.append( perf_counter_ns() )

    slidervar.set( rnd( 10 ) ) # arbitrary change
    label1[ 'text' ] = "sampling : {}".format( slidervar.get() )
    root.after(5, change)

def change2() :
    slidervar2.set( rnd( 20 ) ) # arbitrary change 
    label2[ 'text' ] = "sampling : {}".format( slidervar2.get())
    root.after(10, change2)

def closer( ev ):
    root.destroy()
    for a in range( 0, len(delay)-1, 2 ):
        result.append( ( delay[a+1]-delay[a] ) / 1e9 )

    for a in result:
        print( f'{a} nano seconds' )

root=Tk()
root.title("sampling")
root.geometry("300x200")

root.bind( "<Escape>", closer )

slidervar=DoubleVar()
slider=Scale(root,variable=slidervar,from_=0,to=10,label="sampling")
slider.grid(row=0,column=2)

slidervar2=DoubleVar()
slider2=Scale(root,variable=slidervar2,from_=0,to=20,label="sampling2")
slider2.grid(row=0,column=3)

# make labels with names
label1 = Label(text="sampling : "+ str(slider.get()) )
label1.grid(row=1,column=1)
label2 = Label(text="sampling2 : "+ str(slider2.get()) )
label2.grid(row=1,column=2)

root.after(5,change)
root.after(10,change2)

mainloop()
```

Comment: If you change `root.after( 50, event )` to `root.after( 5, event )` it will work but the readings change so fast it is not useful.

Comment: it works fine if sampling rate with this sampling rate but if the sampling rate is 5 ms or less it shows not responding after some time

Comment: @Derek Yeah! I am telling OP same things! It will run function without change in values, most of the time. Which isn't completely unnecessary?

Comment: Yeah @Kshitiz if it's used as a data collector but for human eyes it's a blur.

Comment: I know it changes the value very fast, but want different sampling both of them are fast but comparatively it almost doubles from other, if use command then different sampling rate is not possible

Comment: @PoojaChoudhary if I insert function `event` into your code then it works, except you `change` and `change2` are creating a new `Label` EVERY TIME it is called.

Comment: @Derek I think in `slidervar2.set( rnd( 10 ) )` we can use `20` instead of `10`

Comment: if I use `change` and `change2`  without updating the label it works fine with `after`  but when I check the time difference using time module difference in time varies from 5 to even 18 ms .

Comment: Have tried changing the update times to say 10 and 20 ms?

Comment: even with higher values, there is significant variation in the time interval expected and actual

Comment: With original 5 and 10 ms delays I read only nano second differences using `time.perf_counter_ns()`

Comment: Code is modified to test time delay accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from tkinter import *


def change(val) :
    l1.config(text="sampling : "+val)

def change2(val) :
    l2.config(text="sampling2 : "+val)

root=Tk()
root.title("sampling")
root.geometry("300x200")

slider=Scale(root,from_=0,to=10,label="sampling",command=change)
slider.grid(row=0,column=2)

slider2=Scale(root,from_=0,to=20,label="sampling2",command=change2)
slider2.grid(row=0,column=3)

l1=Label(text="sampling : "+ str(slider.get()))
l1.grid(row=1,column=1)

l2=Label(text="sampling2 : "+ str(slider2.get()))
l2.grid(row=1,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

You don't need to use `.after()` because on changing slider value, function given in command will be executed and you will get the value of slider there. So, now we got value of the slider we can write it in `Label`. We are writing in `Label` in very easy way, just `.config(text=<>)`.

Comment: but I need value with a specified interval, it is used in some other function, but with command it updates the value instantaneously, I need a way where it get the value with some sampling rate.

Comment: Isn't 5ms and instantaneously same? You need to update label in every 5ms?

Comment: actually i need different slider which change value with different sampling rate

Comment: Please explain clearly, what you try trying to do? If possible with explain!

Comment: Actually, I am writing this GUI for motor testing, where different sliders represent different sensor data values and using slider this(sensor data) is provided manually for testing, but different sensor data have different rates at which it provides value to the ECU(electronic control unit) like throttle value in every 5ms and rpm sensor in 10 ms, so it want some function where I change the slider value manually but data is given to the board(or sample code ) where this sensor data value changes with some 
 fixed interval interval